# Разница в циклах

Tags: javascript

Какая разница между циклом

for (let number ***of*** numbers)  и for(let number ***in*** numbers)

Изменение **of и in** что-то меняет в цикле?

Можете пожалуйста рассказать подробнее, в чем отличие **of** от **in?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29285897/7485582

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of - там в конце есть пункт и про отличия. В принципе нечего и добавить)

Comment: Частота использования в моем реальном проекте (раз): `.map(` - 21, `.forEach(` - 10, `.filter(` - 6, `.reduce(` - 4, `for(let ...;...;...)` - 4. Форма `for(;;)` используется для оптимизации. Форма `for(... in` и `for(... of` не используется, хотя в сочетании с `await` имеет шанс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for..of` проходит по элементам коллекций, например, `Array`. `for..of` позволяет использовать `continiue` и `break` для контроля итераций, в отличие от `forEach`

`for..in` проходит по перечисляемым свойствам объекта и вызывает ключ. Не следует использовать с массивами и псевдо-массивами.

Comment: А когда нужно использовать for in?

Comment: @Человек, в случае с объектами и подобными структурами, например, Map

Comment: О_о continue / break работают и для for-in, как и для других циклов.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, поправил

Comment: @Voprositel, `for..in` с Map не будет работать, потому что его ключи не являются свойствами

Comment: Что такое Map??

Comment: @Человек, [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)